# Which of the following sets is a complete set of representatives modulo 7?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Which of the following sets is a complete set of representatives modulo 7?

1) (1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343)

1 mod 7 = 1

8 mod 7 = 1

27 mod 7 = 6

64 mod 7 = 1

125 mod 7 = 6

216 mod = 6

343 mod = 0

2) (1, -3, 9, -27, 81, -243, 0)

1 mod 7 = 1

-3 mod 7 = 4

9 mod 7 = 2

-27 mod 7 = 1

81 mod 7 = 4

-243 mod 7 = 2

0 mod 7 = 0

3) (0, 1, -2, 4, -8, 16, -32)

0 mod 7 = 0

1 mod 7 = 1

-2 mod 7 = 5

4 mod 7 = 4

-8 mod 7 = 6

16 mod 7 = 2

-32 mod 7 = 3

i think its only 1. but wanted to make sure.

Comment: i just did mod for all those 3 sets. and i am getting all of them between 0 to 6. So does this means all 3 sets are complete set of mod 7?

Comment: In order for a set to be a complete residue system mod $m$, there must be $m$ elements in the set, i.e. there cannot be any repeated residues. For example in #1, the integers 1 and 8 are both the residue 1 mod 7, which is a repetition. Also, every single residue between 0 and 6 must be exhibited somewhere in the set. In #1, there are many residues missing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you want a **complete** set whose members are equivalent, modulo 7, to one and only one element of the set: $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, not necessarily in that order. **Each and every one of these numbers must be represented** by one and only one of the numbers in such a set. That is, you want representatives of the equivalence classes, modulo 7 which will consist of ***seven distinct integers***, each one of which can be expressed in one and only one of the following  forms $$(7k_1, 7k_2 + 1, 7k_3 +2, 7k_4 + 3, 7k_5 + 4, 7k_6 +5, 7k_7 + 6), \quad k_i \in \mathbb Z)$$

$(1)$ is not such a set.

**Added**

Note that the elements of $(3)$ represent each equivalence class, modulo 7, and hence forms a **complete** set of representatives: $$ 0\equiv 0 \pmod 7,\quad  \;1 \equiv 1 \pmod 7, \quad -2\equiv 5\pmod 7,\quad \\ 4\equiv 4 \pmod 7,\quad  -8 \equiv 6 \pmod 7,\quad 16\equiv 2 \pmod 7,\quad -32 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$$

Comment: but i recheck number 1 and here what i got 1 mod 7 = 1. 8 mod 7 = 1. 27 mod 7 = 6. 64 mod 7 = 1. 125 mod 7 = 6. 216 mod = 6. 343 mod = 0. they all 0 to 6.

Comment: Do you see that $1$ and $6$ appear more than once, and there is no representative of, e.g., $3, 2, 4,$ or $5$. Each and every  congruence class 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, must be represented, and only once.

Comment: yes, thts wht i have too. may be i not understanding this right. the mod of them all between 0 to 6. for ex(3): its 0,1,5,4,6,2,3. all between 0 and 6.

Comment: Billy: what I posted **in my answer** was meant to give you the solution. I listed each of the elements in $(3)$, and the congruence class each represents: yes, each class is represented by the elements in $\bf(3)$, but **not** by the elements in $\bf(1)$.  My comment to you (which I left right below your first comment) was about your first comment: Pointing out that Number (1) does not satisfy the needed conditions.

Comment: Billy: look at your elements: you want a complete set of all representatives including each of $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. Number one only contains representatives of $0, 1, 6$ which is not a **complete list**.

Comment: ok i think i get it now. so in order to be set it has to be leat one 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 right? ex only set here is set number 3 right?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's exactly correct.

Comment: @amWhy: Yes - very nice and that needs a TU!!! +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

$3)~~ (0, 1, -2, 4, -8, 16, -32)$ is only complete set of $\pmod 7$.

$$0 \pmod 7 = 0$$

$$1 \pmod 7 = 1$$

$$-2 \pmod 7 = 5$$

$$4 \pmod 7 = 4$$

$$-8 \pmod 7 = 6$$

$$16 \pmod 7 = 2$$

$$-32 \pmod 7 = 3$$

they all have a unique solution from $0$ to $6$.

Comment: Great job for adding some more notes. it also helps to format answers using MathJax (see FAQ). So + 1 for adding that! I will also update your answer so you can see how easy it is to do and how much nicer it makes readability. regards